# SQL Server update/insert/delete join question

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

For my senior design project I'm making a iGoogle type application with lots of subtools. The application uses a heavy amount of AJAX. Because of this some information is stored on the page when it is sent to client, so that I can those make updates to tools when they are added/deleted and so on.

My question comes in where security is concerned. I wan't to make sure that data can't be tampered with client side, allowing users to potentially effect other users data.

What I want to do is check the userid when I make an insert/update/delete statement, to make sure that the user is only changing their data.

This isn't a problem with the first table that uses the userid from the users tables as a foreign key. But I have numerous other tables branching off from there.

Is there a way to do with without doing two separate statements/queries? I know I could do a select join, see if such a record exists, then preform the update/insert/delete. Is it possible to do with one statement?

I started looking into subqueries with SQL Server. Can this be done with subqueries?

If this is a stupid question, excuse my ignorance. Still learning. Thanks.

Comment: So what is to stop me from submitting a fake user id with my malicious data?

Comment: I understand your question is only about how to secure the data in SQL Server but this is where design architecture matters. Yes, you should use a stored procedure and yes, you can use either a join or a subquery to determine whether the executing user can manipulate certain data. However, these rules/constraints should "also" be enforced in your UI. Imagine you, as a user, modifying all this stuff in the UI then trying to commit your changes. Then the app yells at you because the back end (i.e. SQL Server) says you can't modify what you've tried to modify. As a user, you just wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one SQL statement, just make sure you pass in the user id into your stored procedure.

Yes, you'll probably use a sub query in the insert statement. If you provide an example of your table structures we could give you a more specific answer.

As regards the security aspect (I know that's not part of your question) how are you passing the userid between the client and server?

Comment: This is an older version of database schema, but good enough: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0Bwy4qFl6LwWXNGQxODg4MGYtYzlmZS00MTZlLWIzNjctNGIxNjRiZWZmNzJj&hl=en

Comment: As for the userid, I was using Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString(); serverside to get userid.

Comment: Unable to retrieve the document for viewing error. You can attach an image with your question or simply provide the schema of two tables. The user table and any other table you're trying to update.

Comment: Which table would you like the example for (Besides aspnet_Users)

Comment: In a production system, the authentication and authorization process will be done in the ASP.NET and business layer. Once the business layer authorizes the action for the user it would make a call to the data layer to do the job. The data layer should not be attempting to authorize the user per se. Of course if there are foreign key relationships etc. those will need to be accounted for. So you should probably take another look at your design. Your question about using a subquery to do an insert/update/delete is still valid in a pure SQL context.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
Select Table1.userId 
From Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.usedId = table2.userId
where table1.userId = @userId
```

if the query returns null, then matching record is found in table2.

Comment: What is "table", in SELECT table.UserId? And this is just doing a join. Further, you say, "if the query returns null, then matching record is found in table2". did you mean "no matching record is found". Nonetheless the question is about updating/inserting/deleting records in a table and not how to do a join.

Comment: I'll edit the code.  I meant 'Select Table1.UserId' not 'Select 'table.UserId' I'll edit the code.  I thought, perhaps, the OP was trying to see if there's a matching userId in table2 before doing the update.